# How to change search parameters using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, microsoft-edge

I made a program that uses Selenium to get a random image from Bing based on a search query that the user inputs. Here's what it looks like:

```
import random
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge

query = "cats" #This can be anything
query.replace(' ', '+')

edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True
edge_options.add_argument('headless')
edge_options.add_argument('disable-gpu')

driver = Edge(executable_path='PATH/TO/DRIVER', options=edge_options)

#The URL that Edge generates when searching on Bing Images
ImageURL=f'https://www.bing.com/images/search?q={query}&form=HDRSC2&first=1&tsc=ImageBasicHover'

driver.get(ImageURL)

#An array with all the images that Selenium finds
all_images = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('mimg')
thumbnail = random.choice(all_images)

#Getting to the HTML that holds the image link
parent = thumbnail.find_element_by_xpath("..")
Grandparent = parent.find_element_by_xpath("..")
neededPage = Grandparent.get_attribute('href')

driver.get(neededPage)
image = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('img')
source = image.get_attribute('src')
print(source)

driver.quit()
```

Everything works just fine but I have and issue. I can only look for static images (Png, Jpg, etc). What if I want to look for GIFs, turn Edge's SafeSearch off or search by upload date? Is there any way to do this from Selenium? Also, I'm only getting 35 results every time I run the code, how can I increase that number?

Comment: Hi, why exactly do you have to use Selenium in this case? I'm not able to find a use case of Selenium in your example. Could you provide more details about the goal that you're trying to achieve? The main usage of Selenium is to interact with browser in an 'end user' manner. Here I see that you just need to call http get request and parse returned html.

Comment: @PiotrM. The first reason is that when searching on Bing's or Google's image engine what you see isn't the actual image but a small version of it, to get the actual image you need to click on it and BeatifulSoup can't do that. The second reason is that when parsing for the <img> tag with BeatifulSoup I get 14 results while with Selenium I get 35, not too many but at least it's something.

Comment: Ok, thx - you've not provide any implementation/pseudo-code of this interactions so I wasn't sure if you really need Selenium.
1) Only 35 results - do you scroll page down? Because results are dynamically added after page scroll
2) what is the problem with GIF files? Could you provide more details?

Comment: @PiotrM. 1) So that was the problem with results amount, thx. 2) You know how when searching for images you've got multiple filters (Image size, Color, Type, etc.) How can I access those options and edit them?

Comment: Ok. so you have to locate the filter elements and interact with them (click), e.g. css selector for type filter can look like that: "span[title='Type filter']"
when you click an element located with this locator you have to locate the type that you want to filter by - for GIF it can be css selector [title='Animated GIF']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're two ways to add the search filters.

1. Add the search parameters in the url.

If you want to add search filters, you can add this parameter in url: `qft=+filterui:xxx`.

For example, if you want to search animated gif in past 24 hours, you can add the following parameter:

```
qft=+filterui:photo-animatedgif+filterui:age-lt1440
```

The full url is like this:

```
https://www.bing.com/images/search?q={query}&form=HDRSC2&first=1&tsc=ImageBasicHover&qft=+filterui:photo-animatedgif+filterui:age-lt1440
```

2. Locate the search filters in the code.

Just like Piotr M says, you can locate the filters using css selector.

For example, if you want to search animated gif in past 24 hours, you can add the following part in your code:

```
filter = driver.find_element_by_id('fltIdtTit')
filter.click()
time.sleep(3)
m = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[title='Type filter']")
m.click()
p = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title='Animated GIF']")
p.click()
n=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[title='Date filter']")
n.click()
q=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title='Past 24 hours']")
q.click()
```

For the search result number, I didn't find there's an option to change it.

Comment: I think that Selenium web elements locators for filtering are quite easy and readable in this case - and they would be more reliable and maintainable than direct usage of url